# What does the undocumented switch, `-v`, do for `tmutil restore` command?

Tags: time-machine, command-line

I couldn't find anywhere what the `-v` switch does with the `tmutil restore` command.
An answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tmutil` *commands* `restore` *verb* syntax is:

```
restore [-v] src ... dst
```

The use of the `-v`*option* produces *verbose output* during the *restore*, i.e. additional information about the *restore* that's not outputted without it.

As a side note, `tmutil -v` will output the *version* of `tmutil`.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a source to authenticate your answer?

Comment: @Eliad, Yes, run the command with and without the `-v` switch and see the difference for yourself. :)

Comment: You're right, it was more obvious with an error-less usage. Thanks